# What is this anime in which the main characters train to stop Satan and they all wear weird suits?

Tags: saint-seiya-omega

I only remember a character or two, but please help if possible! All the characters in this anime wear weird suits, and they train to stop Satan. There are 4 main characters in total that I know of.

Character 1 is one of the main characters. He has long blue hair, light blue eyes. His body is weak since he has been very sickly since birth. His dad is pretty famous. He trains diligently, and is loved and cared for by everyone in the school. His suit is blue and VERY powerful, and he is very kind.

Character 2 is the main protagonist. He has red hair. He is a big "do it now" kind of guy, and is new to learning how his suit works. In the first episode, his mom was taken by Satan. That's why he trained so hard to get his suit more powerful and stronger to help him. His dad is like a huge god or something. He is good at making enemies, leader of their "pack" (as I call it), helpful, and is not afraid to ask for help.

In the last episode I watched, they had to find some partners to pair up with. Character 1 partnered with a female protagonist and character 2 partnered with a male protagonist, who was the first character to be introduced. Character 1 fought an enemy that wanted him dead or something, and his friend got hurt in the process. The second character helped his friend pass the course and win. Same with the first character and friend. In the end, all four of them passed, then they competed with each other in a battle. That's all I know.

Comment: Do you have any pictures? I might be able to figure it out then.

Comment: It might be worth reading the (lengthy) TV Tropes [Red Oni, Blue Oni](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/RedOniBlueOni/AnimeAndManga) page and seeing if any of the examples ring a bell.

Comment: No sadly I don't have a picture I wish I did but sorry this is all the information I have

Comment: Matt Nordhoff sorry no it wasn't there but yes it did ring a few bells.

Comment: Character 1: his name starts with R, he is sooooo nice to everyone, and I think he is first seen in episode 3

Comment: Oh and they are JUST FRIENDS, not partners or anything, nothing more. Just wanna put that out there before anyone gets the wrong idea

Comment: this sounds like Devilman

Comment: Try using Akinator, the Web Genius. Tell me if you find the right anime, it seems quite interesting.

Comment: Akinator was fun to use, but with what I had to go on was kind of fruitless.  I found a neat site via Google that has an anime character database. Using the advance search option would probably be your best bet.
Here is the link: http://www.animecharactersdatabase.com/searchacdb.php

Answer (score 3):

This is a quite wild guess but it could be [**Saint Seiya Omega**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Seiya_Omega):

> The storyline of Omega takes place 25 years after the Holy Wars of the 20th century narrated in the original manga and its anime adaptation. The goddess Athena is still on Earth after reincarnating to continue her duty of protecting peace against several antagonistic deities. Athena and a new generation of Saints prepare to face new threats that lurks in this new era, in which Pegasus Seiya, the protagonist of Kurumada's manga, is revered as a Saint of legend and one of Athena's Gold Saints.

The two characters you are referring to could be:

- **Dragon Ryuhou**:

  > Very caring of others by nature, Ryuhou suffers from a frail health. Calm and polite, he has a natural talent for becoming a formidable Saint, but he is affected by his condition. He received the Dragon Cloth from his father, the legendary Dragon Shiryu. The young Ryuhou commands the element of Water. After Genbu's death, Geki entrusts the Libra Cloth to Ryuhou so that he can give it to his father.
  >
  > [image: Dragon Ryuhou]
- **Pegasus Koga**

  > The main protagonist in the series, trained since his early childhood to become a Saint, Koga is rebellious but also compassionate. He is still unaware of the purpose of having become a Saint in an era of peace, and has yet to discover his destiny. He meets Seiya, who teaches him the importance of friendship.
  >
  > [image: Pegasus Koga]

The other two characters you mentioned could be **Aquila Yuna** and **Lionet Soma**.

[image: Aquila Yuna] [image: Lionet Soma]

The plot will match your description even more if you replace Satan with the Greek god of war Mars, who in any case has a devilish aspect.

[image: pic4]